# How to write out 28,358,292,110 in english

Tags: numbers

28,358,292,110 
Is this twenty eight billion, three hundred fifty eight million, two hundred ninety two thousand, one hundred and ten dollars if it is written out?

Comment: A reader wouldn't know that you meant dollars unless you included a dollar sign ($) before the number or the word _dollars_ after it.

Comment: Yes, barring a dyslexic episode, that's how you'd write it.  But note that very few publications would use that form for such a large number, preferring to either use decimal digits or approximate it using something like "a little over twenty-eight billion dollars".

Comment: Some people would put hyphens between words like "twenty-eight" and "fifty-eight," etc.  Just as @HotLicks did.  For instance, [take a look at this check.](http://thelottolife.com/storage/2016-08-23_19-32-08.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1471937597044)

Comment: Some would also add a sprinkling of *and*s (e.g. ... three hundred *and* fifty-eight million ...).

Comment: I would move the 'and' out unless I had cents:  one hundred ten dollars, or one hundred ten dollars *and* nine cents.

Comment: [American vs. British English: meaning of “One hundred and fifty”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/american-vs-british-english-meaning-of-one-hundred-and-fifty) You'd never say *one hundred and fifty TENS* would you? Then why is there an *and* in there?  "When saying or writing out numbers, **the British insert an and before the tens and units**, as in one hundred and sixty-two or two thousand and three. **In the United States it is considered correct to drop the and**, as in one hundred sixty-two or two thousand three."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placement of commas and 'and' in English numerals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116236/placement-of-commas-and-and-in-english-numerals)

Comment: Doesn't this also depend on BrE vs AmE in that billion means different things in the two languages?

Comment: @eyeballfrog No. The 'billion' is nowadays defined as 1000 million in 'British English' also. –

Comment: Yes it is, Edwin; so long as you give it a comma…1,000 million in 'British English' please.

Are you as old as me, and able to remember when people minded? I think it took roughly from about 1960 to about 1970 for we Brits to drop the distinction and accept the US billion.